# Making sticky results in Search API Solr

Tags: 7, search

We want to be able to promote some nodes on the search results.
I thought about using the "Sticky" option, so if a node is sticky, it should be on top of the results.

I've tried using the "Boost" option in the index field settings but it doesn't work.

Is there any way of achieving that?

(Using Drupal 7, Apache Solr 4.6.1 and Search API)

Answer (score 1):

Could you perhaps?:

1. Put a boolean field on your content (or make use of the 'promote to front page' field)
2. [Make a view](https://www.drupal.org/node/1597930) to arrange your search results
3. Group by that boolean (or 'promoted')

I don't know if 'promoted' is indexed by default, you might need to set that.